# Classifying the singularities of the a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Classify all the singularities of the following functions

$$ f(z) = \frac {z^2 - 1} {(z^3 + 1)(z-2)^3} $$

$$ g(z) = \frac {e^\frac{1}{z}} {\sin z} $$

I set the denominators equal to zero and solved for z and found these solutions:

For $ f(z) $:

z = -1 simple singularity

z = 2 singularity of order 3

For $ g(z) $:

z = 0 simple singularity

How do I identify which ones are removable?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

You missed a couple of singularities of $f$. The term $z^3+1$ has roots other than $-1$. Maybe factor $z+1$ out and use the quadratic formula?

The function $g$ has a much more terrifying singularity at $0$. It is not always enough to just check the vanishing of the denominator to find singularities. Notice that the numerator of $g$ has a $1/z$ which is going to cause singular behavior. Use the Taylor series of $e^w$ and substitute $w=1/z$
 to see what kind of singularity it is.

Comment: Awsome! For $ f(z) $ : I factored out $ z+1 $ and solved the quadratic formula and got z = 2 singularity of order 3 (pole of order 3). and single singularities at $ z = -1, \frac {1+i \sqrt{3}} {2},  \frac {1-i \sqrt{3}} {2} $. My question is how do I find out if they are removable or not. Thank you.

Comment: For $ g(z) $ : I followed the steps that you suggested but I think I got the wrong answer: z = 0 is a singularity pole of order $ \infty $ because after using the Taylor series expansion for $ e^\frac{1}{z} $ I had an infinitely many terms and all of them had z in the denominator and the power is going up to infinity.

Comment: If there are infinitely many terms of negative power in the Laurent series at a point, the point is no longer called a pole. It is called an essential singularity. Also, you only get removable singularities if the zero of the denominator is cancelled by a zero in the numerator. In your case, factor $z^2-1$ and see if it cancels any of the terms in the denominator.